# PHP mail function not working in godaddy account

Tags: php

The code is shown below

```
<?php
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
 $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers))
{
echo "success";
}
else{
echo "failure";
}
?>
```

This code works perfectly in my server but it moved to GoDaddy server it shows the success message but i didn't get the mail.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: no errors.when I execute it.it shows the success message but I don't receive the mail.

Comment: Probably because GoDaddy doesn't allow using `mail` for sending. Use an SMTP way of sending mail.

Comment: check the email sending feature is enabled or not on your server.

Comment: `$to = "mymail.com";` replace with `$to ="mymail@gmail.com";`

Comment: checked spam box?